# Crystal reports on Visual Studio 2010 - ODBC login 64 bit

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have a .NET 1.0/VS 2003 application with Crystal reports that uses a MS Access DB. I'm migrating it to .NET 4.0/VS2010. The 32-bit application works fine, but the 64-bit doesn't. To begin with, I found out that the OLE DB driver that I used doesn't (and wont) exist in 64-bit version, so I installed the recommended "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable". Windows forms application succesfully connects to DB, but Crystal Reports doesn't - any attempt to display a report in the report viewer component fails with the message "Failed to load database information...". So I try to use ODBC driver, which works on 32-bit version but not on the 64-bit version.

This is how I changed the code to use ODBC:

```
foreach (Table t in rpt.Database.Tables)  
{  
    TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();  
    logOnInfo = t.LogOnInfo;  
    ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();  
    connectionInfo = logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo;  
    string MyConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=" + lib.LokacijaBaze + ";Uid=Admin;Pwd=;";  
    DbConnectionAttributes logonProperties = new DbConnectionAttributes();  
    logonProperties.Collection.Set(DbConnectionAttributes.CONNINFO_CONNECTION_STRING, MyConnectionString);  
    logonProperties.Collection.Set(DbConnectionAttributes.CONNINFO_DATABASE_DLL, DbConnectionAttributes.DATABASE_DLL_CRDB_ODBC);  
    connectionInfo.Attributes.Collection.Set("QE_LogonProperties", logonProperties);  
    connectionInfo.Attributes.Collection.Set(DbConnectionAttributes.CONNINFO_CONNECTION_STRING, MyConnectionString);  
    connectionInfo.Attributes.Collection.Set(DbConnectionAttributes.CONNINFO_DATABASE_DLL, DbConnectionAttributes.DATABASE_DLL_CRDB_ODBC);  
    connectionInfo.Attributes.Collection.Set("QE_DatabaseType", "ODBC (RDO)");  
    connectionInfo.Attributes.Collection.Set(DbConnectionAttributes.QE_DATABASE_NAME, "");  
    connectionInfo.Attributes.Collection.Set(DbConnectionAttributes.QE_SERVER_DESCRIPTION, "");  
    connectionInfo.AllowCustomConnection = true;  
    connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "";  
    connectionInfo.ServerName = "";  
    connectionInfo.Password = "*****";  
    t.ApplyLogOnInfo(logOnInfo);  
}
```

I installed the app on Windows 7, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10, used Process monitor and CR debugging and the only thing I found interesting is a call to PETestDBlogonCredentialsW which returns an error code 717, at the moment CR returns the error to the user. There's almost no mention of this procedure on the net.

Example of files in %TEMP% dir with the 32-bit app displaying the CR report:

```
JETC56A.tmp  
temp_7844824b-03af-410c-9042-27ec4d6741eb 3160_2236_{27BB8BE0-4523-4066-A1BE-F8F5C72ABA95}.rpt  
temp_7844824b-03af-410c-9042-27ec4d6741eb.rpt  
~cpe3160_1432_{947C2812-32A4-444C-8657-5C2431DD90B9}.tmp  
~cpe3160_1432_{CDDC4503-1527-4DFC-838F-57E441BB6957}.tmp  
~DFF57DAAAFA49DD59E.TMP
```

Example of files in %TEMP% dir with the 64-bit app failing on the CR report:

```
temp_45e6a8ee-67e2-4cae-81a5-c0b30095a504 2088_1924_{6A1E4C48-79BE-4868-9473-A27DB83D5FBC}.rpt  
temp_45e6a8ee-67e2-4cae-81a5-c0b30095a504.rpt  
~DF8073F035A3067531.TMP
```

I also tried to install older versions of CR runtime (from 16 down to 13), tried to install 32 and 64 bit versions together, but nothing helped. I read the info to look for ACCESS DENIED message in Process monitor, but nothing there, just bunch of reading of registry keys and the like.

Any ideas to make the 64 bit CR work?

---

There are numerous examples, but I haven't found a sigle one that works.

Here's whar I try next:

```
DatabaseController databaseController = rpt.ReportClientDocument.DatabaseController;
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.ConnectionInfos connectionInfos = databaseController.GetConnectionInfos(null);
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.ConnectionInfo oldConnectionInfo = connectionInfos[0];
//CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.ConnectionInfo newConnectionInfo = new CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.ConnectionInfo();
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.ConnectionInfo newConnectionInfo = oldConnectionInfo.Clone(true);
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag QELogonProperties = new CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag();
QELogonProperties.Add(DbConnectionAttributes.CONNINFO_CONNECTION_STRING, MyConnectionString);
QELogonProperties.Add(DbConnectionAttributes.CONNINFO_DATABASE_DLL, DbConnectionAttributes.DATABASE_DLL_CRDB_ODBC);
QELogonProperties.Add("UseDSNProperties", false);
QELogonProperties.Add("Trusted_Connection", false);
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag QEProperties = new CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag();


QEProperties.Add("QE_LogonProperties", QELogonProperties);
QEProperties.Add(DbConnectionAttributes.CONNINFO_CONNECTION_STRING, MyConnectionString);
QEProperties.Add(DbConnectionAttributes.CONNINFO_DATABASE_DLL, DbConnectionAttributes.DATABASE_DLL_CRDB_ODBC);
QEProperties.Add("QE_DatabaseType", "ODBC (RDO)");
QEProperties.Add(DbConnectionAttributes.QE_DATABASE_NAME, "");
QEProperties.Add(DbConnectionAttributes.QE_SERVER_DESCRIPTION, "");
QEProperties.Add(DbConnectionAttributes.CONNINFO_SSO_ENABLED, false);


newConnectionInfo.Attributes = QEProperties;
newConnectionInfo.UserName = "Admin";
newConnectionInfo.Password = "";
newConnectionInfo.Kind = CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.CrConnectionInfoKindEnum.crConnectionInfoKindCRQE;
databaseController.ReplaceConnection(oldConnectionInfo, newConnectionInfo, null, CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.CrDBOptionsEnum.crDBOptionDoNotVerifyDB);
```

As a result, on my DEV computer there's no error and the report is empty, on production computers there's an exception "System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect.  at CrystalDecision..." I tried both creating and cloning newConnectionInfo - samo result.

Comment: Maybe you can just compile it as x86 and stick with the 32 bit versons?

Comment: The problem is that the app relies on MS ACE 2010 driver, and the bitness of that driver must correspond to the bitness of MS Ofiice, if installed. So if there's 64-bit MS Office on a PC, my app must be 64-bit too.